# nm-connection-editor doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.04, raspberrypi

Running 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B.  I'm connected to wifi and am attempting to share the internet connection with another computer over ethernet.  I've attempted to set up internet connection sharing [using `nm-connection-editor`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#GUI_Method_via_Network_Manager_.28Ubuntu_14.04.2C_16.04.29) but it does not seem to have any effect whatsoever.  Even if I configure a static IP address using this panel there is no change in the output from `ifconfig`.  I've explicitly selected the `eth0` interface in `nm-connection-editor`, and I have rebooted the machine.

The output from `ifconfig` indicates that the `eth0` interface has an ipv6 address but not an ipv4 address.

I've also told `nm-connection-editor` to disable ipv6 on its interface, but this also does not result in any change in the output from `ifconfig`.

`ifconfig` is able to set a static ipv4 address on the interface.

I can't seem to locate any error logs from `nm-connection-editor`: `journalctl` doesn't show anything relevant except that the application was launched from the shell.

Comment: That's an error message from `ifconfig`. It's treating the word "`address`" as a hostname to be looked up. Read `man ifconfig`. Also, don't ask multiple questions, responders may only answer one.

Comment: @waltinator It seemed potentially related to the issue.  Also, the `ifconfig` manpage is confusingly written in that it's difficult to tell which options are literals and which are variables.